# JAVA or my IDE's limitation or SQL issue?

Tags: java, sql, swing, netbeans, combobox

I have created a form in Java and I am sending a number of details to database like Name, Type, Date of Event, Time of Event etc.

- conn is called from DB class I created.
- state variable is stated in the same file (as global variable).

Below is the 'Create Event' button's code:

```
// Creating Events
    try {
        if (txtType.getText().equals("") || txtDate.getText().equals("") || txtDescription.getText().equals("") || cmbTime.getSelectedIndex() == 0 || txtName.getText().equals("") || cmbColor.getSelectedIndex() == 0 || cmbVenue.getSelectedIndex() == 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "All Fields Are Required To create an Event");
        } else {
            int record = conn.state.executeUpdate("insert into Events values('"+txtCustID.getText()+"','"+txtName.getText()+"','"+txtType.getText()+"','"+cmbColor.getSelectedItem().toString()+"','"+txtDescription.getText()+"','"+cmbVenue.getSelectedItem().toString()+"', '"+txtDate.getText()+"' , '"+cmbTime.getSelectedItem().toString()+"' , GETDATE() )");
            if (record > 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Event Registered Successfully!");
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Event Not Registered!");
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ex.getMessage());
    }
```

Problems:

1. The same SQL query is working fine at friend's end but giving me 'Column count mismatch' error. The SQL database has all the required fields (I checked again).
2. Instead of using 'Select' (as a placement text) in all combo boxes I want the combo boxes to show no text but I don't see any option in Netbeans to do that. Is it the limitation of JAVA itself or my IDE?
3. Currently the user has to click and select an item from combo boxes. I want to open the combo boxes as soon as the user Focus on them. There's an event called 'FocusGained'. Is it the right event to use here? What should I code in it to open the combo box as soon as it gained the focus?

[image: SQL Database image]

Comment: Well the `Date` and `Time` values are of concern

Comment: They're populating fine in SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Learn to use `PreparedStatement`s, see [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for more details;
2. Use something like `JComboBox#setSelectedItem` to pass it `null`, this will cause the `JComboBox` to be empty initially.
3. Yes, see [`JComboBox#showPopup`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#showPopup())

As to your first problem, it's impossible for us to tell, as we don't have access to the database, but you should make sure that the database you are connecting is the database you think you're connecting to.

In your insert statement you should also be specifying the columns you want to insert into, not just the values, as the order might change...for example...

```
insert into Events (..., ..., ...) values (?, ?, ?)
```

I'd also discourage you from using the form editor, learn how to hand code your UI's, it will give you a greater understanding of how the UI's work as well as how to take the full advantage of the form editor in the future

Comment: The database is same. I checked it with Login form.

Is it best practice to separate column name and values? I have changed the values a number of times, so if I use separate column and values in that query then I have to change both of them every time.


What language is used for creating UI in Java? (I always used Form Editor)

Comment: Then you are either adding more or less values to the table then you realise (or which are available).  The form editor is simply a editor around [Swing]([Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)).

Comment: I can see you adding 9 values, but I don't have access to your database, so it's impossible to know.  Is the `ID` column auto incrementing?

Comment: Yes, it is. I am attaching an image.

Comment: It's likely that the database doesn't like you trying to set the value of an auto incrementing column...

Comment: Tried the query is SQL. It added data without any issue.

Comment: Give the fact that the `Date` and `Time` columns are of `DATE` and `TIME` values, it might not like you using `txtDate.getText()` as a value in the query, it may not like the fact that it's quoted either.  You should use a `PreparedStatement` and use `setDate/Time` instead